# Bansuri sound producing

Tags: flute, bansuri

I have started learning bansuri, I learnt how to produce sound and finger placements. But my doubt is that whether I'm sounding correctly or not. Is there any way I can find whether I'm sound perfectly or not?

And also, I'm not able to differentiate between whether I'm playing high notes or low notes.

I'm learning myself from internet.

Answer (score 1):

Look on the internet for videos of the pieces you are learning, played by experts. Their sound is what you should be aiming for. Your sound will very probably be more airy and less focussed than the masters, but it will improve with practice. Comparing your playing with a video will also tell you if you are playing the notes in the right octave (assuming that's what you mean with not being able to differentiate between high and low).